# weak convergence of dirac measure $\delta_{\frac 1 n}$

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, measure-theory, measurable-functions

On the [Wikipedia page for weak convergence of measures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convergence_of_measures#Weak_convergence_of_measures) it is written

> For example, the sequence where $P_n$ is the Dirac measure located at
> $\frac 1 n $ converges weakly to the Dirac measure located at $0$ (if
> we view these as measures on  $\mathbb {R}$ with the usual topology),
> but it does not converge strongly. This is intuitively clear: we only
> know that  $\frac 1 n $ is "close" to $0$ because of the topology of
> $\mathbb {R}$.

I don't understand that example. I am just starting that whole subject and I struggle to understand the nuances.

Can someone use that example to distinguish strong and weak convergence ?

---

My attempt leads to strong convergence of the Dirac measure. Using the same definition as the ones on the wiki page:

$$\int \phi \ d \delta_{\frac 1 n} \rightarrow \int \phi \ d \delta_{0}$$
the same way that
$$\lim \delta_{\frac 1 n} (A)= \delta_{0} (A)$$

as well as :

$$|| \delta_{\frac 1 n} - \delta_{0} ||_{TV} = 0$$

My reasoning is simply taking the limit and trivially $\frac{1}{n}$ converges to $0$. What am I doing wrong ? What am I thinking through wrongly?

Please be gentle, I am not used to that field of maths, I really don't know what I should be careful about.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The statements follow from the definitions of different convergence properties.

For weak convergence, we need to check

$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi \ d \delta_{\frac 1 n} =\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi \ d \delta_{0},$$
for any given bounded continuous function $\phi$ on $\mathbb{R}$. This is true since by definition of Dirac measure and continuity of $\phi$, we have
$$\lim_{n\to \infty}\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi \ d \delta_{\frac 1 n} =\lim_{n\to \infty} \phi({\frac 1 n})= \phi(0) =\int_{\mathbb{R}} \phi \ d \delta_{0}.$$

For strong convergence, we need to check $$\lim_{n\to\infty} \delta_{\frac 1 n} (A)= \delta_{0} (A),$$
for any given Borel measurable set $A\subset \mathbb{R}$. This is false since if we take $A=(0,1)$, then 
$ \delta_{\frac 1 n} (A)=1$ for all $n$ but $\delta_{0} (A)=0$.

Convergence in TV norm is even stronger than the strong convergence, since we need to check $$\lim_{n\to\infty}\sup_{A} |\delta_{\frac 1 n} (A)-\delta_{0} (A)|=0,$$
where the supremum is taken over all Borel measurable sets $A\subset \mathbb{R}$. The above counterexample shows that it is false.